# Where fragments should be created? In viewModel or Activity?

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin

I'm trying to learn MVVM pattern and I'm doing an example project with it. But I can't figure it out that fragments should be created in ViewModel or Activity.

I have created them in activity but whenever rotation changes it's all being recreated. This is my code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        popularFragment = FragmentPopular()
        discoverFragment = FragmentDiscover()
        favoritesFragment = FragmentFavorites()

        setFragment(popularFragment)

        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    }

    fun setFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_main, fragment).commit()
    }
```

So how can I create them in ViewModel and whenever rotation changes fragments should stay the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have created them in activity but whenever rotation changes it's all being recreated

That is perfectly normal.

> So how can i create them in viewModel

You don't. You give the fragments their own `ViewModel`, and the `ViewModel` will be retained across the configuration change.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i also have bottom navigation view and it has 3 buttons (popular,discover,favorites). Each one shows their own fragments. And problem is when app first run, popularFragment shows and if i click discover button, discoverFragment shows and if rotation changes, popularFragment shows again. How to prevent that?

Comment: @Itachi: If that has not already been covered in a Stack Overflow question, I recommend that you ask a separate question on that topic.